# C# Run method after PerformClick

Tags: c#

I have problems with button `PerformClick()`.

In my main form I'm loading another form 30 times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < iloscIteracji; i++)
{
    pso _pso = new pso(czastki, punkty, 1, 3, 3,1);
    _pso.Show();
}
```

then in `Form1_Load` I'm checking settings of constructor

```
    if (ktoraMetoda == 1)
    {
        button1.PerformClick();
        radioButton1.Checked = true;
        textBox1.Text = "100";
        button3.PerformClick();

    }
```

but the problem is that in `button3_click` I have 2 methods which I want to run:

```
znajdzNajlepszych();
zmienKolory();
```

and that doesn't work. I tried to put breakpoint on those 2 methods but the app is just leaving them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So when you say "That doesn't work," what do you mean?  The methods are not getting called?  It's throwing an exception?

Comment: Is this Windows Forms? ASP.NET? WPF?

Comment: I think you need to show us a little more code.  Show us your `znajdzNajlepszych();` declaration, and the code block that calls it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS2010 does not show unhandled exception message in a WinForms Application on a 64-bit version of Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a)